# Can't find Nomad clients in the Nomad UI

Tags: consul, nomad

Can't find Nomad client, but I can see all servers and I also can find the clients in Consul.

Nomad config

```
data_dir = "/opt/nomad/data"

server {
  enabled          = true
  bootstrap_expect = 3
  retry_join = ["provider=aws tag_key=Function tag_value=consul_client"]

}

client {
  enabled = true
}
```

Clients in Consul UI:

[image]

---

Servers in Nomad UI:

### [image]

Clients in Nomad UI:

### [image]

So why do I see only one Client in the last screenshot?

Comment: Im having same issue, one of many clients is showing up in consul gui, and consul members list, but not on the nomad GUI clients list.  From the cmd prompt on this absent client  `nomad server members` does show the servers.  i just cant figure out why its not showing up in the nomad gui clients list, as you pointed out above.

Comment: Ok i figured it out, as you mention, the nomad config was set to an old advertise ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out, I should make separate config files for server and client instead of combining them together.

Answer (score 0):

check the advertise ips on the nomad config file, to make sure they are updated to the correct ip address, e.g. for missing client @10.183.141.53

```
advertise {
    http = "10.18.41.53:4646"
    rpc = "10.18.41.53:4647"
    serf = "10.18.41.53:4648"
}
```